# bootstrap modal gridview dropdown get data key

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a asp.net c# application and on one page i have a modal.

the modal displays a usercontrol which is rendered as a string from an AJAX call.

the usercontrol contains a gridview and there is a dropdown within an item template.

what i am not successful is that i want to call a jQuery function when the dropdown selection changes.

the question is how can i get the datakey value of the row from which the dropdown control fired?

the code to access the dropdown event:

```
    $(function () {
    $(".ddlclass").change(function () {
        var c = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        alert(c);
    });
});
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: that retuns the parent but i have no idea about how to get the datakey for the row that was clicked?

Comment: The Datakey can't be accessed by jQuery, it is a server side value. I would return the key.Value to a string in a hidden field for each row, then use jQuery to read the value.

Comment: do you have an example of how access the hidden field in each row using jQuery?

Comment: have a look at the DataKeyArray class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datakeyarray.aspx - You can get the value and return it as a string when the GridView is databound. They include an example.

Comment: i know how to do that. my question was once the datakey is in a hidden field then how to access it via jQuery?

Comment: $('.element').val(); will return the value of the hidden field. 'element' will be the selector name, either unique or access it through the parent() of your .ddlclass

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use a live event:
(I'm assuming that .ddlclass is referencing a  < select > box)

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('change', '.ddlclass', function(){
        var c = $(this).val();
        alert(c);
    });
});
```

post up your resulting HTML if you want a more in depth response.